# transposing excel data from 1 column into multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro to convert one column of data I obtained from the internet into usable content. 
The data is in the cells a1 to a540, I want to transpose the data such that 
the data from cells a1 to a9 becomes a1 to i1,
data from cells a10 to a18 becomes a2 to i2, and so on.

Please help me.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using `PasteSpecial` -> `Transpose`

If you want to automate it, then record a macro and check out the code it produces

---

Also, here is a bit of VBA that may get you on the right track....

It's a bit hack and slash though

```
Public Sub TransposePaste()


'Value we want to step by
Dim stepVal As Long
stepVal = 9


'Declare start row variable (-1)
Dim row As Long
row = 0

'Declare the column the data is coming from
Dim col As Long
col = 1

'Declare and set worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

'end row of the data
Dim endRow As Long


endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row

    'cycle to end of data end of data...
    For i = 1 To endRow Step stepVal

    'increment row each time
    row = row + 1

        'cycle through the columns outputting the data
        For j = 1 To stepVal

        Sheet1.Cells(row, j).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + j - 1, col).Value

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

From:

[image: From_1]

To:

[image: To_1]